# File owner when having a non-root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm setting up a Django project with a `Dockerfile` and I'm wondering about the correct ownership when having a non-root user.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV DIR=/data
ENV USER=files

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 -r ${USER} \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --no-log-init -r -g ${USER} ${USER}

WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ${DIR}/

RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root

ADD . ${DIR}

RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${DIR}
USER ${USER}
```

There are two things that I'm not sure if they're needed, but I've seen them in a few articles. Could someone please elaborate why/if I'd want them.

1. `--gid 1000` and `--uid 1000`
2. `RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${DIR}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either.  There are a number of other things that can be cleaned up in this Dockerfile too.

On the `chown` first: you probably want your application source code to be owned by root, and to be world-readable but not world-writeable (generally mode 0644 or 0755).  That prevents a potential security issue where a bug in your code accidentally overwrites part of your application's source code or static assets.

The open question here is if you need to keep persistent data in your container.  Try to avoid this if you can, storing data in somewhere like an external database; this will help you update your image and will help if you need to run multiple replicas of the container.  If you need that, keep the data somewhere separate from your main application directory, and `chown` that single directory to the non-root user.

The non-root user can have any user and group ID.  It doesn't specifically need to match any given host user's, and indeed trying to make it match isn't a best practice (I'm on a Mac so my uid is 501; do I need to rebuild the Docker image?).

If I were updating this I'd also avoid the two `ENV` variables; these directories and user names will probably be fixed in the image, you don't need to refer to them often, and changing them at runtime won't have an effect.

This would change the Dockerfile to:

```sh
FROM python:3.7-slim

# with a fixed username; without a fixed uid
RUN useradd --no-log-init -r files

# with a fixed path; then use . everywhere afterwards
WORKDIR /data

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root
# prefer COPY to ADD
COPY . ./
# no need to RUN chown; leave the files owned by root

# if you need a local data directory only
# RUN mkdir data && chown files data

# specify the runtime user and default CMD
USER files
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

If you have a writeable data directory, and you need it to be a bind-mounted host directory, and that's owned by some user, you can specify the user ID when you run the container.

```sh
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $PWD/data:/data/data myapp
```